# Photoshop cc exporting for web gif exposure issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, video

I am trying to export a video file into a gif by saving for web in Photoshop cc. However, the color exposure get blown out. Anybody know how to avoid this? or fix it? I know the video has a lot of images in it so there is a lot of different colors, but I need it to stay the same color.[image]e color.

Answer (score 2):

So you have max 256 colors in GIF and millions in your source image.
What you can do is to choose the way how this millions of colors will be reduced to 256.
Try to change Reduction and Dither Algorithms. Usually the Adaptive with No Dither or Diffusion is best.
If Photoshop still uses completely wrong tones, change them manually in Color Table.